# auto deploying static nuxt js project with github action

Tags: github, nuxt.js, github-pages, github-actions

Hi i created a repository with the same name of my github account called **mortezasabihi**. and in this repository i pushed my personal website (nuxtjs static) to it and created github action for autodeployment, but I don't know why my github page URL is this:
[image]

I want to be https://mortezasabihi.github.io.

this is my gh action:

```
  
name: cd

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  cd:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node: [14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup node env
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn

      - name: Generate
        run: yarn run generate

      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

what's wrong? I didn't understand!

Answer (score 2):

The own [action-gh-pages documentation](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-set-another-github-pages-branch-publish_branch) allows you to configure many things inside your workflow file.

You can have one site published to `https://<username>.github.io` by publishing to the `master` (or `main`) branch of a repository named “username.github.io” (substituting your actual `username`), [as explained here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site).

You can also have an additional site per GitHub project published to `https://<username>.github.io/<project>` (which seems to be what you did here using your username profile repository).

Project sites will publish whatever you push to the `gh-pages` branch by default, but you can [change the publishing source in the repository settings](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).

Another description is available in the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages), including options for using custom domain names.

Comment: my code was in another branch and I didn't merged my code with master. i did it but my website didn't published to https://mortezasabihi.github.io. i didn't set ```destination_dir``` or sth like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have my personal website on Github pages too, and use this strategy:

I create a branch named `development` and working on that branch.

Based on `Nuxt` [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/github-pages/), I add some script in my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=master --cleanup"
},
```

and when running these commands, the `dist` folder automatically will be pushed to master.

```
npm run generate
npm run deploy
```